# For Unitarians! Is the being at Genesis 16:10 who multiplied Hagar's descendants the same being who multiplied Abram's descendanst at Genesis 17:1-2?

Tags: abraham, unitarianism, covenants, biblical-unitarian

Genesis 16:10, "Moreover, the angel of the Lord said to her, "I will greatly multiply your descendants so that they shall be too many to count." Vs11, "The angel of the Lord said to her further, Behold, you are with child, and you shall bear a son; and you shall call him Ishmael, because the Lord has given heed to your affliction."

At vs13, "Then she called the name of the Lord who spoke to her, "Thou are a God who sees", for she said, "Have I even remained alive here after seeing Him?"

Genesis 17:1-2, "Now when Abram was ninety-nine years old, the Lord appeared to Abram and send to him, I am God Almighty; Walk before Me, and be blameless. Vs2, And I will establish MY covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply you exceedingly." Vs3, "And Abraham fell on his face, and God talked with him, saying," Verses 4-7 God reiterates His everlasting covenant with Abram, who is now called "Abraham."

So again, here's my question? Is the angel of the Lord who multiplied Hagar's descendants the same being who appeared as God Almighty at Genesis 17:1-2 who multiplied Abraham's descendants? Please provide Biblical evidence for you position.

Comment: Can you say more about the specific issues arising for Unitarians with this question as you see it?

Comment: Sure! I'm asking is the angel of the Lord who multiplied Hagar's descendants at Genesis 16:10 the same being (claiming to be God Almighty at Genesis 17:1-2) who multiplied Abram's descendants? It's a pretty straightforward question. If you say "no" please provide Biblical proof/evidence for you answer. If you answer is "yes," please provide Biblical evidence/proof that confirms your "yes" answer. Another way to look at this is to explain why God would use an angel to multiply someone's descendants when at Genesis 17:1-2 He does it Himself? So far all I see is "crickets."

Comment: Since it's an angel, I think BUs would say the angel is simply an agent of the Father (i.e., God) and speaking as God's agent. This is a point that trips up Trinitarians - the agent can speak as the one who sends the agent. Cf. the messengers of the centurion in the NT - in 2 Gospels, it's messengers, in 1 the centurion himself. Well, which is it? The ancient Jewish mind did not distinguish like we tend to. Since no one has seen the Father, who is Spirit, God appeared to Abraham through an angel. Whether they are the same angels, dunno.

Comment: But this is a more general issue, no? There are many such appearances of God in the OT, so the question is what exactly is happening.

Comment: I can see the point of the question, the distinction between angelic presence toward Hagar would have been a lesser presence than that Presence through Whom Abraham had a mediated interaction with Almighty God. But I do not think that a Unitarian would appreciate that difference. Hence they would not have an answer to that. (Up-voted +1.)

Comment: The first case is explicitly called an angel (messenger). The second case *could* be interpreted either as a messenger or, more likely, as YHWH himself. But either way, what difference would it make to anyone, and in particular why would unitarians want to interpret it differently from trinitarians?  — Possibilities: angel-1 and angel-1, angel-1 and angel-2, angel-1 and YHWH. How do those possibilities relate to {uni,trini}tarianism?

Comment: @RayButterworth Ya, I think that's probably the options. "as YHWH himself" The question is what exactly does it mean for Yahweh Himself to 'appear', since Yahweh is Spirit. A Trinitarian might want to hold these are other 'incarnations', and could explain the Word incarnating as one along a pattern. I don't know how common that tack is, though. Whatever the case, Unitarians wouldn't have that option - it's not the Son in earlier incarnations.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I first want to compliment you for at least trying to answer the question. I don't know why some other Unitarians are silent. In any case I'm going to answer my own question. I want to address one your comments. You cannot "assume" that the angel of the Lord is an actual angel. The Hebrew word for "angel" is "malak." The word simply means "messenger." The context determines how it is used. Example, Malachi 3:1. "Behold I am going to send my "malak/angel/messenger" and he will clear the way before Me. In this case John the Baptist is a human who cleared the way of the Lord.